# How to publish to a development slot in Azure from VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-deployment-slots

I have an App Service app and a development slot 
[image: slot azure]

I see them too on Vs Code
[image: VS Code]

But when I publish I can not select the slot
[image]

Any idea please?

Regards

Answer (score 9):

The solution is right click the slot in VSCode and execute Deploy slot command

Thanks

Comment: For those facing the same issue, it is worth noticing that, while working, this approach won't build the application like the standard deploy option would do, so it has to be done manually.
I had to publish the app first using `dotnet publish -c release` and then deploy to a slot like mentioned in this answer and selecting the `publish` folder which contains the `web.config`.

Answer (score 0):

As @kintela has identified it can be done by right clicking on the slot. But this does not always work as there seems to be a bug in the AZ VS Code extension that sometimes doesn't allow the slot to be selected for deployment even if it is right-clicked on.

It is possible to instead deploy from the AZ CLI. You'll first need to zip the contents of your dist folder.

Then:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group [resource-group] --name [web-app-name] --src [./path/source.zip] —slot [staging-slot-name]
```